# Eclipse calling IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have written an eclipse plugin in 3.7 and in my Action delegate which gets called when user chooses a menu option I would like to call another Action Delegate.

To be more specific, I have an action delegate and I would like to call the equivalent of Team -> Refresh action (Specifically Perforce).

The relevant action class is `com.perforce.team.ui.p4java.actions.RefreshAction` however how can I construct, init and call a method?

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Other than finding the class that implements the Refresh action, where are you stuck?

Comment: I do have the relevant action class but how am I suppose to call this?